# having an error when one wants to plot quintuple

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a data but I get error. I don't understand the error, if one could help me, I would appreciate it a lot

```
grid.newpage()
venn.plot <- draw.quintuple.venn(
  area1 = 1068,
  area2 = 1092,
  area3 = 1077,
  area4 = 1083,
  n12 = 1027,
  n13 = 1023,
  n14 = 1027,
  n23 = 1042,
  n24 = 1048,
  n34 = 1045,
  n123 = 1000,
  n124 = 1005,
  n134 = 1004,
  n234 = 1023,
  n1234 = 989,
  category = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  fill = c("dodgerblue", "goldenrod1", "darkorange1", "seagreen3"),
  cat.col = c("dodgerblue", "goldenrod1", "darkorange1", "seagreen3"),
  cat.cex = 2,
  margin = 0.05,
  ind = TRUE
)
```

> Error in draw.quintuple.venn(area1 = 1068, area2 = 1092, area3 = 1077,
>   :    Unexpected parameter length for 'category'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the `draw.quintuple.Venn` function says "Draw A Venn Diagram With Five Sets." You have four areas/ categories/ fills/ etc.

So, use `draw.quad.venn` instead:

```
venn.plot <- draw.quad.venn(
  area1 = 1068,
  area2 = 1092,
  area3 = 1077,
  area4 = 1083,
  n12 = 1027,
  n13 = 1023,
  n14 = 1027,
  n23 = 1042,
  n24 = 1048,
  n34 = 1045,
  n123 = 1000,
  n124 = 1005,
  n134 = 1004,
  n234 = 1023,
  n1234 = 989,
  category = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  fill = c("dodgerblue", "goldenrod1", "darkorange1", "seagreen3"),
  cat.col = c("dodgerblue", "goldenrod1", "darkorange1", "seagreen3"),
  cat.cex = 2,
  margin = 0.05,
  ind = TRUE
)
```

Comment: can you make a 4 Venn ?